# How to send data directly to XPS printer in delphi using the flag XPS_PASS

Tags: delphi

Need to send data directly to XPS printer in windows 7 and above using flag XPS_PASS as mentioned in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2779300/v4-print-drivers-using-raw-mode-to-send-pcl-postscript-directly-to-the however this flag is not defined in Delphi.

Comment: It's a string, not a flag. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/sending-data-directly-to-an-xps-printer).

Comment: Both `'XPS_PASS'` and `'RAW'` in the link you posted are in quotes, which means they are strings, not flags. `XPS_PASS` is a flag, `'XPS_PASS'` is a string. The one you're looking for is the latter.

Comment: Hi thanks but the question is using Delphi not C++. Which method should be called in Delphi where I can send data and specifying 'XPS_PASS'? I know ExtEscape that works with RAW and PASSTROUGH that are defined in Delphi, but it does not recognize XPS_PASS.

Comment: Once again, `'XPS_PASS'` is a **string**. There's nothing for Delphi to recognize, because it's not a **flag**. There's nothing for Delphi to *recognize*, any more than there is when you write `UserName: string;` followed by `UserName := 'Roberto';`.

Answer (score 1):

`XPS_PASS` is not a flag. It's a character string that indicates the document type. The other possible value is `RAW`, which is also a character string.

Here's a quick direct translation (compiled, but untested) of the example code Microsoft provides in [How to Send Data Directly to an XPS Printer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/sending-data-directly-to-an-xps-printer)

```
uses
  Winapi.WinSpool;

function RawDataToXpsPrinter(PrinterName: String; Data: TBytes; DataCount: Cardinal): Boolean;
var
  hPrinter: NativeUInt;
  DocInfo: DOC_INFO_1;
  PrintJob: Cardinal;
  BytesWritten: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := OpenPrinter(PChar(PrinterName), hPrinter, nil);
  if Result then
  begin
    DocInfo.pDocName := PChar('My Document');
    DocInfo.pOutputFile := nil;
    DocInfo.pDatatype := PChar('XPS_PASS');

    PrintJob := StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, @DocInfo);
    if (PrintJob > 0) then
    begin
      Result := WritePrinter(hPrinter, Data, DataCount, BytesWritten);
      EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
      if Result then
        Result := ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
      Result := Result and (BytesWritten = DataCount);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

It's up to you to find the proper name of the XPS Printer driver to pass as `PrinterName` and put the data you want to print into a `TBytes` array to pass to the function as `Data`. `DataCount` would be the length of that data. Presumably you've already got that, as your question here was only how to pass `'XPS_PASS'`.

Comment: Printing to XPS or PDF normally prompts you for a filename. The above process of using OpenPrinter and WritePrinter does not. However, if you specify a filename for pOutputFile, the PrintJob is always 0.